# Changing the name of the function key <mouse-1> leads to problems

Tags: key-bindings

I want to change the name of the function key `<mouse-1>` like so:
`(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "<mouse-1>") (kbd "<jd:m1>"))`
And thus bind the new name to an arbitrary function like so:
`(define-key global-map (kbd "<jd:m1>") 'mouse-set-point)`
But when testing the changes I get this error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "mouse-set-point must be bound to an event with parameters")
  call-interactively(mouse-set-point nil nil)
  command-execute(mouse-set-point)
```

Why does this functionality work for all other key functions but not the mouse key functions?
For example this works just fine:

```
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "<tab>") (kbd "<jd:tab>"))
(define-key global-map (kbd "<jd:tab>") 'indent-for-tab-command)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is the following:

```
(define-key input-decode-map [mouse-1] [jd:m1])
```

will convert any incoming "event with name `mouse-1`" into the event `jd:m1`, whereas you want to convert it to a similar "event with name `jd:m1`".  More specifically, mouse events are not just symbols but have the form:

```
(NAME . METADATA)
```

where `NAME` may be equal to things like `mouse-1` and `METADATA` holds info such as the location where the user pressed this mouse button.

IOW, your remapping turns `(mouse-1 . METADATA)` into a "dumb" `jd:m1` losing the `METADATA` along the way.

Doing the kind of remapping you propose is actually tricky for all kinds of arbitrary reasons.  I suggest you look at the source code of `mouse--click-1-maybe-follows-link` to see what it might involve.

Basically, you'll need something like:

```
(define-key input-decode-map [mouse-1]
  (lambda (&optional _prompt)
    (let ((newname 'jd:m1))
      ;; Copy the `event-kind` at the first occasion.
      (unless (get newname 'event-kind)
        (put newname 'event-kind
             (get (car last-input-event) 'event-kind)))
      ;; Modify the event in-place, otherwise we can get a prefix
      ;; added again, so a click on the header-line turns
      ;; into a [header-line header-line <newname>] :-(.
      ;; See fake_prefixed_keys in src/keyboard.c's.
      (setf (car last-input-event) newname)
      (vector last-input-event))))
```

Yuck!

Comment: So I'm assuming that the events `<vertical-line>` and `<mode-line>` both have metadata associated with them as well? When events like, `<escape>`, `<return>`, and `<tab>`, etc. are dummy events with only a key press that's associated with them..? Or I guess a better follow up question would be how in the world you found out that the `<mouse-1>` event has the form `(NAME . METADATA)`?? I can't M-x describe that or anything, and I wouldn't know where to start to find information like that.

Comment: @JohnDeBord: Actually, I think that those pseudo events like `mode-line` and `vertical-line` don't carry any metadata.  You can figure it out by looking at the shape of the value of `last-input-event` during the remapping, but for that you need to use a function like I did (IOW, you already need to know more than you originally did).

Comment: Ok. Well it just dawned on me...How in the heck do I just rename this fricken symbol (or symbols) without going through all the hassle of converting the events. I don't care if I have to modify the source code or anything. I've gone down this rabbit hole for far too long and I just need something to show for it.

Comment: Really would appreciate a quick response. This is going to be my project for the night. But I understand if you're busy.

Comment: @JohnDeBord: response to what question?

Comment: Oh sorry. Just how do I go about renaming `<mouse-1>`, `<mouse-down-1>`, `<vertical-line>`,  `<mode-line>`, etc? I'll modify the source code or do whatever it takes. I just don't want to be messing around with modifying the events and whatnot. Or is this even possible?

Comment: @JohnDeBord: Have you tried my code?

Comment: @Stefen I have not. It looks very esoteric to me, and I'm trying to avoid putting anything in init file that it too overly complex for my current understanding of Elisp.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83201/discussion-between-john-debord-and-stefan).